# How to color each edge of a graph with two colors?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, color

This is a chord visualization taken from [here](https://doc.lagout.org/science/0_Computer%20Science/3_Theory/Mathematics/Mathematica%20Data%20Visualization%20%5BSaquib%202014-09-17%5D.pdf). The corresponding code for visualization is

```
g = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "LesMiserables"}, "FullGraph"]
v = VertexList[g]
e = EdgeList[g];
r = 10;
tsep = 1.0;
ang = 2 Pi/Length[v] + 0.0;
gelt2 = Table[vind1 = Position[v, e[[i, 1]]][[1, 1]];
   vind2 = Position[v, e[[i, 2]]][[1, 1]];
   {Opacity[0.5], RGBColor[0.6, 0.729, 1], 
    BSplineCurve[{{(r - 0.5)*Cos[ang*vind1], (r - 0.5)*
        Sin[ang*vind1]}, {0, 
       0}, {(r - 0.5)*Cos[ang*vind2], (r - 0.5)*
        Sin[ang*vind2]}}]}, {i, 1, Length[e]}];
gdyn = Table[cv = v[[j]];
  tempe = EdgeList[g, cv \[UndirectedEdge] _];
  rot = (ang*j > Pi/2) && (ang*j < 3*Pi/2);
  Mouseover[
   (*if mouse not on top*)(*render the character name*)
   Rotate[Text[
     Style[(*Limit the character name to 8 characters only*)
      If[StringLength[cv] > 8, StringTake[cv, 8] <> ".", cv], 
      Medium], {(r + tsep)*Cos[ang*j], (r + tsep)*Sin[ang*j]}], 
    If[rot, ang*j - Pi, 
     ang*j]], {(*if mouse on top*)(*render the character name*)
    Rotate[
     Text[Style[cv, Medium, Blue, 
       Bold], {(r + tsep)*Cos[ang*j], (r + tsep)*Sin[ang*j]}], 
     If[rot, ang*j - Pi, ang*j]],(*render thick bsplines curves*)
    Table[vind1 = Position[v, tempe[[i, 1]]][[1, 1]];
     vind2 = Position[v, tempe[[i, 2]]][[1, 1]];
     {Thick, 
      BSplineCurve[{{(r - 0.5)*Cos[ang*vind1], (r - 0.5)*
          Sin[ang*vind1]}, {0, 
         0}, {(r - 0.5)*Cos[ang*vind2], (r - 0.5)*
          Sin[ang*vind2]}}]}, {i, 1, Length[tempe]}] (*end of thick b-
    spline table*)} (*end of Mouseover second argument*)
   ],(*end of Mouseover*){j, 1, Length[v]}];(*end of gdyn table*)
```

The corresponding visualization is:

[image]

Now I wish to color each edge with two colors - the first half with one color and the second half with another color and all the edges from the same vertex should have the same color. A sample is shown below:

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update 2:** An alternative approach that gives better-looking curved edges:

```
ClearAll[eSF, vSF]
eSF[clr_Association] := (Quiet@GraphComputation`GraphPropertyChart[]; 
  GraphComputation`GraphChartDump`pEdge[blah, blah, blah, #1, #2]/.
   Style[circ_Circle, _] :> circ /.  Circle[aa_, bb_, cc_] :> 
    MapThread[Function[{x, y}, {x, Circle[aa, bb, y]}], 
     {clr /@ {First@#2, Last@#2}, Partition[Subdivide[## & @@ cc, 2], 2, 1]}]) &;

vSF[clr_Association] := Module[
  {off = If[-Pi/2 < ArcTan @@ # < Pi/2, Left, Right]},
  {clr @ #2, Text[Style[Framed[#2, FrameStyle -> None], 
       FontSize -> Scaled[.03]], #, {off, Center}, 
       ArcTan[#] (off /. {Left -> 1, Right -> -1})],
     PointSize[Large], Point@#}] &;
```

***Example:***

```
g = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "LesMiserables"}, "FullGraph"];

vColors = AssociationThread[VertexList[g], 
   RandomSample[ColorData[{"Rainbow", {1, VertexCount@g}}] /@ 
     Range[VertexCount[g]]]];

SetProperty[g, {ImageSize -> Large, 
  GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding", 
  VertexShapeFunction -> vSF[vColors], 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> eSF[vColors]}]
```

[image]

**Update:** You can also use  custom  functions for the options `EdgeShapeFunction` and `VertexShapeFunction`:

```
ClearAll[eSf, vSf]
eSf[g_, cols_] := Module[{bsf = BSplineFunction[{#[[1]], 
     RegionNearest[Disk[Mean[#[[{1, -1}]]], Norm[#[[1]] - #[[-1]]]], {0, 0}], #[[-1]]}], 
     p1 = Subdivide[0, 1/2, 50], p2 = Subdivide[1/2, 1, 50]}, 
   {Thin, cols[[VertexIndex[g, #2[[1]]]]], Line[bsf /@ p1], 
     cols[[VertexIndex[g, #2[[2]]]]], Line[bsf /@ p2]}] &;
vSf[g_, cols_] := Module[{off = If[-Pi/2 < ArcTan @@ # < Pi/2, Left, Right]},
   {cols[[VertexIndex[g, #2]]], 
    Text[Style[Framed[#2, FrameStyle -> None], FontSize -> Scaled[.03]],
       #, {off, Center}, ArcTan[#] (off /. {Left -> 1, Right -> -1})],
    PointSize[Large], Point @ #}] &;
```

**Example:**

```
g = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "LesMiserables"}, "FullGraph"];
cols = RandomSample[ColorData[{"Rainbow", {1, VertexCount@g}}] /@ Range[VertexCount[g]]]; 

SetProperty[g, {ImageSize -> Large, GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding", 
  VertexShapeFunction -> vSf[g, cols], EdgeShapeFunction -> eSf[g, cols]}]
```

[image]

You can add `Epilog -> Circle[]` in the second argument of `SetProperty` above to get:

[image]

**Original answer:**

You can use `BSplineFunction`:

```
cps1 = {{8, 5}, {0, 0}, {10, 1}};
Graphics[{Thick, Red, Line[BSplineFunction[cps1] /@ Subdivide[0, 1/2, 50]], 
   Blue, Line[BSplineFunction[cps1] /@ Subdivide[1/2, 1, 50]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: The visualization looks much better now with the chords of different sizes. The answer is already acceptable to me. However, since you have answered it, I feel a bit greedy. You have already removed the circular outline which is great. Can you please put a colored dot at each end as updated in my question?

Comment: @Majis, please see the update.

Comment: I like the first one.

Comment: Great answer! I used the provided functions in [a call-graph-making package](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/Misc/CallGraph.m); see https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1580800 .

Comment: Thank you @AntonAntonov; happy to hear that it was useful.