# Plotting Graphs with edges that have two colors

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks, color

I want to plot a coloured Graph in Mathematica. The speciality, however, is that my edges can have two colours. Color A close to vertex A, and colour B close to vertex B. I was able to find plots for coloured graphs, and multi-edges with different colours, but not single edges with two colours.

An example of such a graph can be seen here:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate: [How to color each edge of a graph with two colors?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/188390/125)

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/154638) as well?

Comment: Thank you kglr and JM. Those codes appear to be related, but i wonder whether this actually works. In particular, a vertex can have several different incoming colored edges, thus the edge color cannot be inherited from the vertex (JM's link). And it seems in kglr's link, there is a third hidden vertex that defines the boundary of monochromatic edges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** An alternative `ChartelementFunction` that gives curved edges:

```
ClearAll[ eSF]
eSF[clr_Association] := (Quiet@GraphComputation`GraphPropertyChart[];
 GraphComputation`GraphChartDump`pEdge[True, blah, blah, #1, #2]/.
   Style[circle_Circle, _] :> circle /. 
    Circle[center_, radius_, angles_] :> 
      MapThread[Function[{x, y}, {x, Circle[center, radius, y]}], 
       {clr@#2, Partition[Subdivide[## & @@ angles, Length[clr@#2]], 2, 1]}])&;
```

***Examples:***

```
edgecolors = {{Blue}, {Red, Blue}, {Green, Blue}, {Purple}, {Blue}, {Red, Blue}, 
  {Green, Blue}, {Purple}, {Purple}};
coloring = AssociationThread[edges, edgecolors]; 

Graph[Reverse@{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}, edges, 
 GraphLayout -> {"CircularEmbedding", "Offset" -> Pi/8}, 
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> .25, 
 VertexStyle -> White, 
 VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Times", Large], 
 EdgeStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[.7], AbsoluteThickness[10]], 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", EdgeShapeFunction -> eSF[coloring]]
```

[image]

Use

```
SeedRandom[1]
edgecolors = RandomColor[RandomInteger[{2, 5}]]& /@ edges;
coloring = AssociationThread[edges, edgecolors];
```

to get

[image]

**Original answer:**

An approach that works for graphs without multi-edges:

```
edges = DirectedEdge @@@ {{a, h}, {a, g}, {a, f}, {f, e}, {b, c}, {b, d},
   {b, e}, {g, d}, {h, c}};
```

Specify a list of colors for each edge:

```
edgecolors = {{Blue}, {Red, Blue}, {Green, Blue}, {Purple}, {Blue}, 
   {Red, Blue}, {Green, Blue}, {Purple}, {Purple}};
```

Construct an `Association` for coloring rules:

```
coloring = AssociationThread[edges, edgecolors];
```

A custom `EdgeShapeFunction` that divides each edge into colored segments:

```
eShapeFunction = Module[{c = coloring @ #2, bsf = BSplineFunction @ #, 
    s = Subdivide[Length @ coloring @ #2]}, 
  {CapForm["Butt"], Thread[{c, Line /@ Partition[bsf /@ s, 2, 1]}]}] &;


Graph[Reverse @ {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}, edges, 
 GraphLayout -> {"CircularEmbedding", "Offset" -> Pi/8}, 
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> .25, 
 VertexStyle -> White, 
 VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Times", Large], 
 EdgeStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Round"], Opacity[.7], AbsoluteThickness[15]], 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", EdgeShapeFunction -> eShapeFunction]
```

[image]

We can have arbitrary number of colors for each edge. For example, change `edgecolors` to

```
SeedRandom[1]
edgecolors = RandomColor[RandomInteger[{2, 5}]] & /@ edges;
```

to get

[image]

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much! Have to try to understand it now :)

Comment: Since your updated eShapeFunction, double edges are not loops anymore. But the associated colors seem wrong. if you try `edges = DirectedEdge @@@ {{a, h}, {a, h}, {a, f}, {f, e}, {b, c}, {b, 
     d}, {b, e}, {g, d}, {h, c}};`, i would expect that between a-h, there are two edges. one Blue, one Red-Blue. However, in the code both are Red-Blue

Comment: @MarioKrenn, If you have version 12.1  you can try  if `EdgeTaggedGraph`. If it doesn't, i suggest you post a new question for the multi-edges case (I don't see a simple modification of the current post to handle multi-edges).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i did ask a [new question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/222040) and will accept your answer here in a day or so. Thank you very much for your help!