# Make Graphs with disjoint edge sets that have different colors?

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

I would like to obtain the related graphs in mathematica which look like the following picture [took from this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2220726/433264):
[image: graphs]
**What I do:**

- I have all the edge lists for the above graphs.

```
edgelist = {
{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4, 6}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 6}, {3, 5}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}}, {{1, 6}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}}},
{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 6}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 3}, {4, 6}}, {{1, 6}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}}}, 
{{{1, 2}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 6}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}}}, 
{{{1, 2}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 6}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 3}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}}, {{1, 6}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}}}, 
{{{1, 2}, {3, 6}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 6}, {3, 5}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 3}, {4, 6}}, {{1, 6}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}}}, 
{{{1, 2}, {3, 6}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4, 6}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 3}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 6}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}}}
};
```

- then I assign each edges set with the below color setting:

```
colorlist = {Red, Black, Yellow, Green, Blue};
edgecolors = {};
Table[AppendTo[edgecolors, Flatten[Tuples[{colorlist[[i]]}, {Length[DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[edgelist[[1]]]]]/2, 1}], 1]];, {i, 1, Length[edgelist[[1]]]}];
edgecolors = Flatten[edgecolors, 1];
```

- Inspired by [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/222043/55474), I modified a bit the code as the following which should give me the graphs stored in `allGraphs`.

```
allGraphs = {};
getvetex={1,2,3,4,5,6} ;
For[ii = 1, ii <= Length[edgelist], ii++,
  
  edges = UndirectedEdge @@@ Flatten[edgelist[[ii]], 1];
  taggededges = EdgeList@EdgeTaggedGraph@edges;
  coloring = AssociationThread[taggededges, edgecolors];
  eShapeFunction = Module[{c=coloring@#2, bsf=BSplineFunction@#, s=Partition[Subdivide[Length@coloring@#2], 2, 1]}, {CapForm["Butt"], Thread[{c, Line /@ (bsf /@ Subdivide[##, 100] & @@@ s)}]}] &;
  
  ggg = Graph[getvetex, taggededges, GraphLayout -> {"CircularEmbedding", "Offset" -> 0}, 
    VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> .2, VertexStyle -> White, 
    VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Times", Medium], 
    EdgeStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Round"], AbsoluteThickness[3]], 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", EdgeShapeFunction -> eShapeFunction];
  AppendTo[allGraphs, ggg]; (*store all graphs*)
 ];
```

However, there is a problem: it seems graphs are replaced by the last one in `allGraphs`, therefore I only have the last repeated graph in `allGraphs`. When I add `Print[ggg];` before  `AppendTo[allGraphs, ggg];`, I could have the correct answer. **I have no idea why.**

Also is there other simple approach to do the above task such as using `HighlightGraph` or `GraphHighlightStyle` options? Thank you very much!

Comment: The reason why your code returns a list of identical graphs is that you are reassigning `coloring`, and your `eShapeFunction` is only evaluated at the end. You can use `With` or similar to "inject" the value of `coloring` into the function body

Comment: thank you for the answer! that's an interesting point, I thought the ```eShapeFunction``` was evaluated in each iteration. @LukasLang

Comment: @Xuemeito to be more precise: `eShapeFunctiom` is only evaluated when the graph is displayed (when `MakeBoxes` is called on it). You can partly verify this by looking at the `InputForm` of the graphs: the `eShapeFunction` definition will still be in there in its unevaluated form. This also explains why it works when you print them in each iteration: in that case, `MakeBoxes` (and by extension also `eShapeFunction`) is called during each iteration, when `coloring` is still correct

Comment: thank you for the nice explanation!@LukasLang

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
stylededges = Join @@ MapThread[Thread @* Style, {#, colorlist}] & /@ 
      (edgelist /. {i_Integer, j_Integer} :> UndirectedEdge[i, j]);

gr = Graph[#, 
    GraphLayout -> {"CircularEmbedding", "Offset" -> 0}, 
    VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
    VertexSize -> .2, 
    VertexStyle -> White, 
    VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Times", Medium], 
    EdgeStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Round"], AbsoluteThickness[5]], 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"] &;

Multicolumn[gr /@ stylededges, 3, Appearance -> "Row"]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can style edges using `MapIndexed` + `Style` as follows:

```
stylededges2 = Join @@ 
   MapIndexed[Thread[Style[#, colorlist[[First @ #2]]]] &, #] & /@ 
    (edgelist /. {i_Integer, j_Integer} :> UndirectedEdge[i, j]);

stylededges2 == stylededges
```

> ```
> True
> ```

**Update:** A simpler alternative: use `colorlist` and lengths of edge groups to construct a list of styles and use it with the option `EdgeStyle`:

```
edgeStyle = MapThread[Apply[Sequence]@*Table, {colorlist, Length /@ edgelist[[1]]}];

edges = Join @@@ edgelist /. {i_Integer, j_Integer} :> UndirectedEdge[i, j];

gr2 = Graph[#, 
    EdgeStyle -> Thread[# -> edgeStyle], 
    GraphLayout -> {"CircularEmbedding", "Offset" -> 0}, 
    VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> .2, 
    VertexStyle -> White, 
    VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Times", Medium], 
    BaseStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Round"], AbsoluteThickness[6]], 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"] &;

Multicolumn[gr2 /@ edges, 3, Appearance -> "Row"]
```

[image]

**Update 2:** Using `HighlightGraph`:

```
HighlightGraph[Graph[Join @@ #, 
     GraphLayout -> {"CircularEmbedding", "Offset" -> 0}, 
     VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> .2, 
     VertexStyle -> White, 
     VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Times", Medium], 
     BaseStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Round"], AbsoluteThickness[5]], 
     PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], 
   MapThread[Style, {#, colorlist}]] & /@ 
      (edgelist /. {i_Integer, j_Integer} :> UndirectedEdge[i, j]) //
 Multicolumn[#, 3, Appearance -> Row] &
```

[image]

Comment: that's a very elegant solution, which is much simpler! Thank you very much!

Comment: thank you so much! btw, do you have any idea about the strange issue to append graphs in the loop without using ```Print```?

Comment: @Xuemei, can you add the definition of  `getvetex`. Without it we can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: oops, sorry. thank you for pointing out the missing part ```getvetex={1,2,3,4,5,6} ;```

Comment: @Xuemei, i can reproduce the issue. Can't think of a reason why it is happenning.

Comment: thank you very much for many suggestions! just one strange issue in your code: It seems that ```(edgelist /. {i_, j_} :> UndirectedEdge[i, j])``` doesn't always work when ```edgelist``` is different from here, such as ```edgelist={{{{1, 6}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}}}, {{{1, 6}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 6}, {3, 5}}}}``` or ```edgelist={{{{1, 4}, {2, 3}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}}}```. do you know why? thank you!

Comment: @Xuemei, replacing `{i_,j_}` with  `{i_Integer, j_Integer}`  should work in general.

Comment: yes, I also think so but the real situation is not, that's strange

Comment: i.e. ```edgelist={{{{1, 4}, {2, 3}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}}}```, when i apply ```edgelist/. {i_, j_} :> UndirectedEdge[i, j]```, the results is ```{{{1, 4} \[UndirectedEdge] {2, 3}, {1, 3} \[UndirectedEdge] {2, 4}, {1, 2} \[UndirectedEdge] {3, 4}}}```, which is wrong. @kglr

Comment: try `edgelist /. {i_Integer, j_Integer} :> UndirectedEdge[i, j]`

Comment: ohh, i see the difference ```i``` is not ```i_Integer```, smart trick! thank you!@kglr